# How install DB2 Express for Windows 7?

Tags: db2

There is a guide or tutorial in spanish, detailed, for the download and instalation of DB2 Express?

I need some one in Spanish for sahre in my work.

Answer (score 0):

I decide to make my own manual, this is a Spanish tutorial for this topic:

http://thenullpointerexceptionx.blogspot.mx/2015/05/instalacion-db2-express-c-database.html